# Bras, kets, a Hilbert space and its dual

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

So I’m trying to get this all straightened out in my head.

In Quantum mechanics we use a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$ as our vector space and we say that its elements is the set of kets $\left|\psi\right>$ that are our state vectors. The bras $\left<\psi\right|$ are the adjoints of $\left|\psi\right>$. The inner product is then $\left<\psi|\psi\right>: \mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}$. I’m all *fairly* comfortable with this, but please point out some errors because I’m almost positive I made some.

Now my main question. What is the dual of our Hilbert space? Is it just the bras? When I look up the definition of a dual space it says it’s the set of all linear functionals that take elements from our vector space and map it to the underlying field. So would it be accurate to say that the bras are not the dual space but instead the dual space is the set of all functionals $\left<\psi|\cdot \right>$ that takes elements of $\mathcal{H}$ as its argument and spits out elements of $\mathbb{C}$ because it’s an inner product?

Sorry if this is worded weird as I’m not used to rigorous mathematical definitions. Please point out my misunderstandings!

Comment: Are you sure this is the proper site for this? You are asking a physically meaningless question about an imagined contrast between bras and their collective  dot products with all kets, the only way the former were defined. Perhaps you'd choose to move it to the MSE?

Comment: Isn’t it physical? I mean it’s Math-y and definition heavy but it deals directly with the inner product (I think) right? Shankar gives a brief description of the dual space in his book, but I didn’t fully understand it. So I came here to clear it up a bit.

Comment: Yes the dual space is just the bras, their action on kets is defined using the inner product as part of their definition as linear functionals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form. But the above comment by cosamas is right in that this is much more math laden than physics and would be an even better fit for MSE

Comment: Dirac, in *his* book, *defines* bras through their dot products with kets. Physically, your pedantic logical alternatives amount to the very [same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) thing.

Comment: Look up [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).